# How can I pass MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN of one Module to another Module?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am trying to build a modularize NestJS application. I have 3 Modules (MainModule, Module A, Module B). MainModule imports ConfigModule and Module A. ConfigModule provides the options needed by Module A, which in turn Module A passes to Module B via its own MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN (I'm using https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#configurable-module-builder).

Module A's import list includes:
`ModuleB.registerAsync({`     
    `useFactory: (options: ModuleA) => {`        
        `return { arg: options.arg };`    
    `},`    
    `inject: [MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN]`
`})`

However, I am getting this error:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CONFIGURABLE_MODULE_OPTIONS[459c60a9a307a6b778aa7] (?). Please make sure that the argument CONFIGURABLE_MODULE_OPTIONS[59c60a9a307a6b778aa79] at index [0] is available in the InternalModuleClass context.

I tried injecting the options/configuration passed to ModuleA to ModuleB but got an issue in the dependency injection.